# Generate View for iPhone application using interface builder.?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I wanted to generate one fix view using interface builder, but the size of that view is exceeding the size of iphone screen,and I am not able to maximize screen. I wanted to show table view in that screen.
I did enabled scrolling but that didn't work,

**Update 1:**
Actually I wanted to show thumbnail image inside cell and i want to show 5 cell so 5 thumbnail image,those images are static. So which is a better way to achieve this ,interface builder or programming?
Hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not terribly clear, so this is the question that I am attempting to answer here:

You want to have a table view which has five rows, each of which has a small image.

Short answer: you *can't* do this entirely in the Interface Builder. What you can do is define your table view, including the "look," scrolling abilities, etc. And then in the same XIB file you would define the table cells (which can include your pictures, captions and what have you).

You then have to connect the two together programatically. Apple provide plenty of examples in the SDK on how to do this.

Comment: thanks for your time,
that's exactly the answer I am looking for.